# Приведение указателя структуры к типу, который лежит первым полем в структуре

Tags: c, структуры, strict-aliasing

Допустим, у меня есть некая структура, так называемая структура для подсчета ссылок:

```
#ifndef LIBKODIK_API_OBJECT_BASE
#   define LIBKODIK_API_OBJECT_BASE             \
uint32_t                        i_refs_count;   \
struct libkodik_api_object_t    *p_parent       \

#endif /* !LIBKODIK_API_OBJECT_BASE */

typedef struct libkodik_api_object_t {
    LIBKODIK_API_OBJECT_BASE;
} libkodik_api_object_t;

uint32_t
libkodik_api_object_retain(libkodik_api_object_t *p_object);

uint32_t
libkodik_api_object_release(libkodik_api_object_t *p_object);
```

```
uint32_t
libkodik_api_object_retain(libkodik_api_object_t *p_object) {
    libkodik_api_object_t *p_current = p_object;
    while (NULL != p_current) {
        p_current->i_refs_count++;
        p_current = p_current->p_parent;
    }
    return p_object->i_refs_count;
}

uint32_t
libkodik_api_object_release(libkodik_api_object_t *p_object) {
    libkodik_api_object_t *p_current = p_object;
    while (NULL != p_current) {
        p_current->i_refs_count--;
        p_current = p_current->p_parent;
    }
    return p_object->i_refs_count;
}
```

И есть другая структура, в которой первым полем лежит `libkodik_api_object_t`:

```
struct kodik_api_countries_t {
    libkodik_api_object_t s_api_base;
    ...
};
```

Могу ли я безопасно вызывать `libkodik_api_object_retain`, `libkodik_api_object_release` делая простой каст указателя на другой тип струкруты?

```
libkodik_api_object_retain((libkodik_api_object_t *) p_countries_api);
```

```
libkodik_api_object_release((libkodik_api_object_t *) p_countries_api);
```

P.S. `libkodik_api_object_release` не освобождает память, а просто уменьшает кол-во ссылок на 1.

Comment: Вы просто хотите вместо `&(p_countries_api->s_api_base)` писать `(libkodik_api_object_t *) p_countries_api`?

Comment: Нет, дело не в этом, а в том, что тип может быть не известен, т.е. его определение видно только в одной единице трансляции.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Да, согласно стандарту<sup>†</sup> (§ 6.5 / 7)

> <sup>(7)</sup> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue
> expression that has one of the following types:
>
> - a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
> - a qualified version of a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the effective type of the object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a qualified version of the effective type of the object,
> - **an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its members (including, recursively, a member of a subaggregate or contained union)**, or
> - a character type.

А также (§ 6.7.2.1 / 15)

> <sup>(15)</sup> Within a structure object, the non-bit-field members
> and the units in which bit-fields reside have addresses that increase
> in the order in which they are declared. **A pointer to a structure
> object, suitably converted, points to its initial member (or if that
> member is a bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice
> versa**. There may be unnamed padding within a structure object, but not
> at its beginning.

Другими словами, указатель на структуру может быть приведен к указателю на первый элемент этой структуры и это не будет являться нарушением strict aliasing rule:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct A {
    int value;
};

struct B {
    struct A a;
};

void print_value(struct A *);

int
main(void)
{
    struct B b = {{42}};
    print_value((struct A *) &b);
}

void
print_value(struct A *a)
{
    printf("%d\n", a->value);
}
```

---

<sup>†</sup> *ISO/IEC 9899:2011 (E)*.

Comment: Древнее подобие плюсового upcasting'a.

Comment: Указатель на структуру может быть приведет к указателю на первый элемент этой структуры. А если наоборот, это все еще будет разрешено?

Comment: @MGNeo, да, я тоже об этом задумался во время чтения вашего вопроса. Мне кажется, что разрешено, но пока что нет возможности привести ссылки. Может быть, вам стоит задать отдельный вопрос на эту тему?