# Реализация интерфейсного типа через каламбур типизации в C

Tags: c, интерфейс, language-lawyer

Рассмотрим следующий код на C:

```
struct base_type
{
    // ...
};
struct complex_type
{
    struct base_type base_type_part;
    int complex_type_part;
};

void function(struct base_type* base_type_ptr)
{
    struct complex_type* complex_type_ptr = (struct complex_type*)base_type_ptr;
    complex_type_ptr->complex_type_part = 1;
}

int main()
{
    struct complex_type complex_type_object;
    function((struct base_type*) &complex_type_object);
    // ...
}
```

Законен ли такой *хак*?

Я поковырял Стандарт, особенно раздел про псевдонимы, и у меня нет ощущения, что такое разрешено, но все так делают.

Если это законно, то каковы основания?

Comment: Похожий вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1185946/185348

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это разрешено и будет работать, как и ожидается. Указатель на первый элемент объекта агрегатного типа всегда равен указателю на сам объект.

> **6.5.9 Equality operators**
> 6 Two pointers compare equal if and only if both are null pointers, both are pointers to the same object (including a pointer to an object and a subobject at its beginning) or function, both are pointers to one past the last element of the same array object, or one is a pointer to one past the end of one array object and the other is a pointer to the start of a different array object that happens to immediately follow the first array object in the address space.

В С++ это свойство называется *pointer-interconvertible*.

А вот что приведенный в примере интерфейс весьма сомнительный - это уже другое дело.

Comment: Спасибо большое за информацию, это именно то, что я искал.

Answer (score 1):

Переопределение типов на абстрактный и потом на родной не приводит к проблемам. Стандарт разрешает и говорит, что будет пахать. Другое дело, у вас ошибка в логике. Вы должны были передавать адрес на `base_type_part` без преобразования типа, а потом делать смещение адреса.

```
# include <stddef.h>
void function(struct base_type* base_type_ptr)
{
    // делаем смещение указателя базовой структуры на
    // указатель родственной
    struct complex_type* complex_type_ptr =
     (struct complex_type*)((char*)base_type_ptr-
       offsetof(struct complex_type,base_type_part));
    complex_type_ptr->complex_type_part = 1;
}

int main()
{
  struct complex_type complex_type_object;
  // спокойно передаём адрес на базовую структуру
  function( &complex_type_object.base_type_part);
  // ...
}
```

Иногда смещение нулевое и кто-то не делает смещение вообще, но на это не стоит полагаться, так как приведёт к тяжёлым багам.

стандарт

> A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a
> different object type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly
> aligned69) for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined.
> Otherwise, when converted back again, the result shall compare equal
> to the original pointer. When a pointer to an object is converted to a
> pointer to a character type, the result points to the lowest addressed
> byte of the object. Successive increments of the result, up to the
> size of the object, yield pointers to the remaining bytes of the
> object.
>
> Указатель на тип объекта может быть преобразован в указатель на другой
> тип объекта. Если результирующий указатель неправильно выровнен 69)
> для указанного типа, поведение не определено. В противном случае, при
> повторном преобразовании результат должен быть равен исходному
> указателю. Когда указатель на объект преобразуется в указатель на
> символьный тип, результат указывает на младший адресованный байт
> объекта. Последовательные приращения результата, вплоть до размера
> объекта, дают указатели на оставшиеся байты объекта.

Comment: Я понял ваш ответ, спасибо. Что касается моего примера, то он однозначно некорректен из-за нарушения требований псевдонимов?