# C++ CONTAINING_RECORD и standart layout

Tags: c++, c, windows, visual-c++, iso

Хочу использовать макрос **CONTAINING_RECORD** на структуре **event_t** и поле **entry**, которое первое в этой структуре:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winnt.h>

struct struct_x_t {
    int x;
};

struct struct_y_t : struct_x_t {
    int y;
};

struct event_t
{
    SLIST_ENTRY entry{};
    std::string string{};
};

static_assert(FIELD_OFFSET(event_t, entry) == 0);   // OK
static_assert(std::is_standard_layout_v<event_t>);  // ASSERT

int main()
{
    SLIST_HEADER header{};
    InitializeSListHead(&header);

    event_t event;
    event.string = "Strangers in the night Exchanging glances Wandering in the night";

    InterlockedPushEntrySList(&header, &event.entry);

    {
        auto* e = InterlockedPopEntrySList(&header);
        auto* event = CONTAINING_RECORD(e, event_t, entry);
        std::cout << event->string.c_str() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Но эта структура не соответсвует требованиям **standart layout** из-за того, что **struct_y_t** унаследована от **struct_x_t** и у них у обоих есть поля.
Нужно ли соблюдать это требование, если офсет у **entry** и так равен нулю и код работает корректно?

Среда: Visual Studio 2017 (15.9.40). Флаги: /std:c++latest

Comment: см https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1340559/%d0%a0%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%84%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bf%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b1%d1%83%d1%80-%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b2-c/1340609#1340609

Comment: Дело в том, что event_t не агрегатный тип. Но CONTAINING_RECORD всё равно работает.

Comment: Я не вижу, где типы `struct_y_t` и `struct_x_t` вообще используются в `event_t`

Comment: `std::string` может как быть, так и не быть standard layout типом

Comment: `FIELD_OFFSET` -- это в смысле `offsetof`, или вопрос именно про `FIELD_OFFSET`?

Comment: Это `[language-lawyer]` вопрос или практический вопрос про реализации?

Comment: `offsetof` и `FIELD_OFFSET ` одинаковы